# other method to loop in array ? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, ecmascript-6

can y'all explain other methods to loop in the array ??

```
function blabla(number){
for ( let i = 0 ; i < number.length ; i++)
 ..........
}


console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6])// true

console.log([2,4,6,8])  // true

console.log([1,2,6,8,9,11, 25]) false
```

can we use forEach to loop? how about map and filter?

Comment: why you need looping and how you're deciding `true` or `false` with looping?

Comment: There are many array methods that iterate and do different things in each iteration. You can look those up on sites like [MSN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). If you want specific advice explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Not getting your question

Comment: No, you should not use `forEach`. `for … of` is the best way to iterate arrays. And `map` and `filter` are not about looping, they are about creating a new array.

Comment: @Bergi how come?

Comment: @evolutionxbox experience.

Answer (score 1):

There's a ton of different ways to iterate through an array.

Let's use this array as an example: `const array = ['foo', 'bar']`

### `for..of`

This will iterate through the **values** in the array.

```js
const array = ['foo', 'bar']
for (element of array) {
  console.log(element)
}
```

### `for..in`

This will iterate through the **properties** in the array. In this case, that would be the array indexes. I wouldn't recommend this to iterate arrays, to be honest.

```js
const array = ['foo', 'bar']
for (element in array) {
  console.log(element)
}
```

### `Array.forEach()`

This will run a callback for each one of the elements in an array. This allows you to pass a function to it, which will take each element as the parameter.

```js
const array = ['foo', 'bar']
const doSomething = e => console.log(e)

array.forEach(element => console.log(element))
//or
array.forEach(doSomething)
```

### `Array.map()`

This will run a callback for each one of the elements in an array, just like in the forEach method, but in that function you can `return` a value modifying the original value of the element, and the `return` value of the map function will be the array with the modified values.

This will add 'test' to the end of each of the elements, and return the resulting array.

```js
const array = ['foo', 'bar']

const mappedArray = array.map(element => element.concat('test'))
console.log(mappedArray)
```

### `Array.filter()`

This will run a function for each one of the elements in an array, and depending whether you return a **truthy** or **falsy**, it will include or exclude that element from the returning array

This will filter out all elements that contain the letter "f".

```js
const array = ['foo', 'bar']

const filteredArray = array.filter(element => !element.includes('f'))
console.log(filteredArray)
```

Those are just some of them. I'd also recommend looking into [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Answer (score -1):

this will start counting from `0`

```
function blabla(number){
    $.each(new Array(number),
       function(n){alert(n);}
    );
}

blabla(3);
```

Comment: What do you want to explain

Comment: what is the purpose of this `blabla(number)` function? why you introduces here jquery?

Comment: I'm not explaining anything. surely the OP has his own reason. so i'm just showing him a different path. thats it.

Comment: You are creating empty array and executing the function. What is the use of that

Comment: If i'm not wrong, `$.each()` can operate only on an `object` thats why. and because the OP wants a different approach, although i would never do it.